# How do you recreate this list using something like listliketab?

Tags: tables, lists, books

So I'm recreating a book in LaTeX and I need to find a way to recreate this type of list.

**Note:** Please make the indent of the paragraph the same as the indent of the list:

[image]

Here's my attempt (MWE):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{listliketab}
\usepackage[
mode=match,
propagate-math-font=true,
reset-math-version=false,
reset-text-family=false,
reset-text-series=false,
text-family-to-math=true,
text-series-to-math=true,
group-separator = {.}
]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
Diện tích cả nước rộng chừng độ \qty{312000}{\square\km} chia ra như sau này:
\begin{listliketab}
\begin{tabular}{l@{~:~}l}
Bắc Việt & \qty{105000}{\square\km} \\
Trung Việt & \qty{150000}{\square\km}\\
Nam Việt & \qty{57000}{\square\km} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{listliketab}
\end{document}
```

The example:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can use `@{\hskip\parindent}l@{~:~}l}` to control the left margin.  {The default is `\tabcolsep`.}